# Designer and programmer simultaneously work

Tags: xaml, mvvm

I am working on WPF application with xaml designer (the man who designes xaml screens :) ).
We are implementing MVVM model. The designer is working on view classes, and I am working on VM and Model classes. I don't want to share with the designer model classes. 
We are working with git.
I have to use model classes in VM. But, if I willn't give him the sources, it will not compile on his machine.

One solution is to send dll's to designer, but it's too complicated to do this each time when some dll was changed.

Is there another way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a separate set of VM classes that have the same properties (so the Bind expressions will be the same) and can be instantiated from design-time data to accommodate design. Compile those into a mock assembly and hand him the assembly.

Once he hands you back the Views, replace the mock assembly with the actual one.

Comment: Yes, but the Mock version could be created automatically by only copying the properties and commands, not the logic in the VM's. There is no silver bullet: you don't want to share the code => you will have to mock it.